# How can you reduce the default ntree=500 parameter passed to RF from caret?

Tags: r, performance, parameter-passing, random-forest, r-caret

I believe the "rf" (`randomForest`) method in `caret` sets the default number of trees at 500. Unfortunately, this causes the time complexity to grow out of control for larger datasets. Is there any quick way to reduce the number of trees without creating a custom method? I know that the only tuneable parameter for rf is mtry.

Just to clarify: I'm not looking to tune on number of trees. I simply want to fix it to a lower value so that I can run rf in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify the ntree parameter when you call train like so:

```
rf <- train(X, y, method="rf", preProcess=c("center","scale"), ntree=100, trControl=fitControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use the `randomForest` library. I have always found that one simpler to use than the one in `caret`, and it has a parameter to set the number of trees.

Comment: agreed, but I'm trying to use caret methods as I've built an ensemble method workflow that takes advantage of the unified interface that caret provides.

Comment: Is this not a worth suggestion though :)?

Comment: No, this is not a good suggestion. caret adds much more than RF. The solution is simply to pass ntrees via the right wrapper function (`getImp*`). Admittedly caret is very obscure on this and it's not documented that getImp* is the general wrapper to randomForest.

Comment: Yes, I recognised there are better solutions in my comment above. However it would be amiss not to mention the randomForest library, thus I did not delete the answer. Or do you think this is a "bad" suggestion? Is there something wrong with the randomForest library (which is directly derived from the original Fortran code)